# Should I use an SMPS cord without an earth-pin?

Tags: power-supply

[image]> **Possible Duplicate:**

> [Does a desktop power supply need to be grounded?](https://superuser.com/questions/198714/does-a-desktop-power-supply-need-to-be-grounded)

A further follow-up to my question [What precautions when using multi-rail SMPS?](https://superuser.com/questions/266729/what-precautions-when-using-multi-rail-smps) ;

Should I use an SMPS cord that lacks an earth-pin?

```
 (o)   ---------------- hole where the earth-pin should be
o   o  ---------------- 1 line pin + 1 neutral pin
```

Comment: @ studiohack - i searched for 'earth' instead of 'ground' without result )+: colloquialisms ...

Comment: Follow-up: Spoke with support, and they said this was for a European style plug which apparently has the earth/ground pin protruding out of the plug socket. Is this right?

Comment: Pretty much yes, that plug is designed for use with frebch and german sockets. French sockets have an earth pin sticking out of the socket, german sockets have the earth on side clips. The problem with this design is that when the plugs end up in other countries and people plug them into adapters or other types of socket they often end up with no earth connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this won't affect the functionality of the power supply, it does compromise the safety of the unit, since a fault such as stray power or wiring failure can cause the case of the computer or power supply to become electrified, creating a risk of electric shock.  The ground pin is intended to prevent electrical current from reaching external metal parts.

You can use the cord, but you shouldn't because it would not be very safe to do so.